# JPA all the objects remain stored in EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a web application created with Spring data, which uses JpaRepository (org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) after some server uptime I have noticed that heap is growing all the time.

After taking a heap dump it shows that heap contains much more entities than I am currently using.

So my question is how to manage EntityManager to clear entities that are not being used any more?

Here is jpa configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:database="${jdbc.databaseType}"
              p:generateDdl="true" p:showSql="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">com.example.db.repository.FixedDefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you use an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`?

Comment: No, do you think that will solve the problem? I have no need to open transaction on each connection, on first access I load everything from database and on last I am saving.

Comment: Post code for you dao and some configuration. My guess improper use of transactions or messing around with `EntityManager` instances yourself without closing them.

Comment: In the edited question I have added jpa configuration. And only thing that I use is JpaRepository methods, like findBy.., findOne, save that is all. Dao's are not complex.

Comment: If the entities remain in memory you must be referencing them from somewhere? You aren't assign them to instance variables somewhere? Also make sure that yuo have proper tx setup (`<tx:annotation-driven >` in your configuration). Unrelated but for cleanup your `hibernate.connection.*` properties are useless, due to the fact that you are injecting a datasource. Saves you 3 lines of xml).

Comment: I have a map (Guava cache), when entity is old it is being removed from cache and saved. In logs I see that my map has about 200 entities, but heap dump shows 5.5k. As I see I cannot find the place where references may be. In heap dump only entity classes are in enormous size.

Comment: Ok looks, like it is a problem with references. Thanks